# Laravel Eloquent get JSON relational nested

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve json nested based on relationship.

Right now I am getting back the following:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Album #1","release_year":2007,"album_id":1,"song_title":"Song #1"},{"id":2,"title":"Album #1","release_year":2007,"created_at":"2014-12-28 01:50:33","album_id":1,"song_title":"Music"},{"id":3,"title":"Album #2","release_year":2009,"album_id":2,"song_title":"Song #2"}]
```

and I would like to achieve something like:

```
{
            title: 'Album #1',
            release: '2007',
            songs: [
            {
                title: 'Song #1'
            },
            {
                title: 'Song #2',
            },
            ]
        }, 
        {
            title: 'Album #2',
            release: '2009',
            songs: [
            {
                title: 'Song #3',
            }
            ]
        }
}
```

I have the following in routes.php

```
Route::get('albums', function() {
    return Albums::getAll();
});
```

and this in Albums.php model

```
class Albums extends Eloquent {
    public static function getAll() {
        $albums = DB::table('albums')
        ->leftJoin('songs', 'songs.album_id', '=', 'albums.id')
        ->get();

        return $albums;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look to model relationships? 
You can do like this:
In your Albums model:

```
class Albums extends Eloquent {
    public function songs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Song');
    }    
}
```

Where 'Song' is the name of the model (maybe you have it as 'Songs'). Then, in the controller you can do:

```
Route::get('albums', function() {
    return Albums::with('songs')->get();
});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships